# Mail sent from localhost but cannot send from online host

Tags: java, email, sendmail

When running on my localhost, my web app is able to send out email, but when I deploy on remote host, it cannot. 
What should I check?

I know it may not be a Java problem, but hope somebody can figure it out. Thanks

Below is the code:

```
public void send() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Properties props = System.getProperties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "103.20.XXX.XXX");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

                Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                //mailSession.setDebug(true);

                try {
                    Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
                    mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(msgFrom, username));
                    mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(msgTo));
                    mailMessage.setSubject(msgSubject);
                    mailMessage.setContent(msgBody, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
                    transport.connect("103.20.XXX.XXX", username, password);
                    transport.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
                    transport.close();

                } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: It seems as if the problem might be firewall/access related.
You can try to telnet in to your smtp server on port 25 from the remote host (if you have terminal/ssh access). Your remote host might also be missing a dependency. Like Darkl Knight said, please share the log trace as well.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have access from remote host to the ip of the SMTP server on port 25.
Most likely it is some kind of firewall rule that blocks you.

To verify this, I usually connect with terminal to the remote host and run

```
telnet <ip> <port>
```

If you get an error like:

```
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

It is definitely a connectivity issue.